# Reading windows registry Reg_SZ in javascript

Tags: javascript, windows, registry

first time posting here!:)

As title says I have a win reg fie (reg_sz) which contains "name" and "value"

```
this.reg = new Registry.Key(Registry.windef.HKEY.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Path\Path\Path', Registry.windef.KEY_ACCESS.KEY_READ);

funct read(this.reg){
var value;
var pushes = [];
            [   
                "food", 
                "veggy", 
                "etc", 
                "etc"].forEach(function(name) {
                try {
                    value = key.getValue(name);
                    entries.push({name: name, value: value});
                } catch (e) {
                }
            });
return pushes;
};
```

example:  `"food"="apple"`

Which my code reads properly, however I came across a issue with special characters, example "ä"

```
"food"="äpple"
```

which my code reads as `�pple`.

My question is what kind of decoding/encoding should i use and what is with this win registry, what exactly are they using? Can it be raw JS preferably and if not what else? I tried using decodeURI/encodeURI but seems like its not the correct approach(dont know what encoding they are using and which decoding should I use)

TLDR: How can i type in "äpple" in win registry and when reading that file with JS get same "äpple" instead of "�pple"

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using to read the registry value please? The JS engine ought to sort this all out for you really, assuming it's using the correct -W versions of the registry read functions. Or if you mean you're reading from a .reg file then that will be encoded as UCS-16: are you opening the file correctly there too? (and can you show us that code please?)

Comment: Rup, i updated the post.

Comment: That doesn't show you reading the value 'food'. Which framework is this please, i.e. what's providing the 'Registry,Key' class?

Comment: After i get this, i have func to append with entries to appead each "name/food" to "value/apple".  Im updating question again

Comment: And https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-registry

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using [windows-registry-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-registry). This is unfortunately a bug in that, [#44](https://github.com/CatalystCode/windows-registry-node/issues/44). The reporter says:

> If i return the raw buffer and use iconv to convert from "ISO-8859-1" to "UTF-8" i get the correct characters

Note that this is assuming the current code page of the system, though, and might not always be correct. (It might be possible to tell iconv to detect and use the current code page?)

The exact problem is in [registry.js](https://github.com/CatalystCode/windows-registry-node/blob/master/lib/registry.js#L69):

```
// READ VALUE
result = advApi.RegQueryValueExA(key.handle.deref(), valueName, null, pKeyType, value,
                                 pKeyDataLength);
```

Here it uses RegQueryValueExA, which means fetch strings as the current Windows code page, as opposed to RegQueryValueExW which would use UTF-16. So value, which is a Node.JS Buffer, does not contain UTF-8. The code then calls Buffer.toString(), which assumes UTF-8 by default:

```
if (value.type === types.LPTSR) {
    // TODO not sure why buffer's utf8 parsing leaves in the unicode null
    // escape sequence. This is a work-around (at least on node 4.1)
    value = value.toString().replace('\u0000', '');
}
```

So this is going to need a fix in windows-registry-node. The best fix is probably to set the code up for UTF-16, using the -W version of the function and  `value.toString('utf16le');`

Comment: So you suggest I just add if (value.type ===types.LPTSR){value.toString().replace('\u0000', ''). Is this correct? Do you think it will do the trick?

Comment: No, sorry, that was quoting another part of the plugin code. I suggest you either pass the string through iconv, asking iconv to detect the current Windows code page if possible, or get windows-registry-node fixed.

Comment: As users will use and manually type in their variaton of "äpple/bännas" or who knows what else, I cant predefine it. So only option is get windows-registry-node-fixed, how do i do this? Sorry for bothering btw. Got me bit confused

Comment: I'd guess this is the fix: https://github.com/RupW/windows-registry-node/commit/5d0438e3eea00793c22f00b9baa67f2c83d47ae8 but I've never built a NPM module with native bindings before and I'm struggling to test it sorry, and I've run out of time to look now.

Comment: Oh now i understand what you are talking about. You want me to rewrite the lib. Sorry. Ill see what i can do. Thanks for everything man!

Comment: Yes I see. Hopefully over the weekend il test and see if it does what it is supposed to. Thanks

Comment: Rup. May i ask you whats the difference between ExW and ExA?

Comment: Broadly (and there must be a good explanation written up somewhere, but I can't find it now), -A mode means use an 8-bit character encoding (from one of many supported by Windows, but not UTF-8) and -W means 16-bits, originally UCS-16 but now UTF-16. The 8-bit character encoding is commonly [Windows CP 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) and any character not in that set cannot be represented. There are exceptions, e.g. Windows does support mutlibyte character sets such as Shift-JIS but not AFAICS UTF-8 as the native 8-bit encoding.

Comment: So as a rule you should always use the -W version of Windows APIs (which can now represent any Unicode value, like UTF-8 can) or you risk losing characters that can't be represented in the selected 8-bit code page. This has been true in consumer OSes since Windows 2000, and arguably true since Windows '95. However the -A versions are simpler for people used to working with char as the basic C character type and not working with the Windows APIs directly.

Comment: I see thanks. I see nobody noticed your fork/issue 44 suggestion. Guess library isnt updated anymore?

Comment: I wouldn't expect them to notice it unless I raise a pull request, and I haven't had a chance to test the change yet (I don't have node-gyp set up and have never used it before, nor do I know if the test cases in the project are enough to verify this anyway) so I haven't done that.

Comment: I haven't forgotten about this, but haven't had much time to spend on it sorry. I do now have a working patch for reading values at least - my original issue-44 branch didn't - but the registry unit tests don't work for me on Windows 10 with or without my change. Someone else has picked this up on GitHub too (I'd guess that's not you?) https://github.com/CatalystCode/windows-registry-node/pull/58

Comment: Finally found some more time to look at this! Here's my PR: https://github.com/CatalystCode/windows-registry-node/pull/60